Do not understand solution to Write a formula with $\mathcal L_{NT}:={0,S,+,⋅,<,E}$ for "x is prime" from Leary and Krisiansen
I'm working through "A friendly introduction to logic" from Leary and Kristiansen and am struggling to understand the solution given to the question in the heading.
The question is from Section 1.3.1, Exercise 3, and the answer given in the book is:
$$Prime(\overline n):\equiv \overline 1 \lt x \land \lnot(\exists y)(\exists z)[(y + \overline 2) \cdot (z + \overline 2) = x]   $$
I read this that a number is prime if it is not 1 and if there does not exist a y and z so that $(y+2)\cdot(z+2) = x$.
I don't understand why $(y+2)\cdot(z+2) = x$ is a test for prime numbers? It obviously works out fine for x equal 7 or 13 (and presumably for all other primes) but I can't see why that is the case.
What is the reason for this?
Reference - Link to book
https://milneopentextbooks.org/a-friendly-introduction-to-mathematical-logic/

What are you struggling with? This is basically the definition of a prime number. $x + 2$ is just any natural number greater than 1.

Ahhh, ok. That's what I was struggling with.... didn't understand what was said there with x+2. Thanks @NaïmFavier!

I think it's worth mentioning that this is not the only formula that works. You can also obtain formulas by directly translating your favourite "natural-language" definition of prime numbers. They'll be a bit longer, but I think that's a much more "friendly" answer, to be honest. (For example: "$n$ is prime if $n \ne 1$ and if for all $k$, if $k \mid n$ then $k = 1$ or $k = n$" works just as well (if you first define "$k \mid n$" and then write it all out in symbols))
